# Make hidden files visible with McAfee in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I use Windows 7 and I set Windows to show all kind of hidden files. It was fine until I installed McAfee Virus Scan which makes hidden files invisible after log off.

1. Changing settings from `Folder Option`  won't work!
2. I used normal protection!

What should I do to prevent McAfee from changing my settings?

Comment: I'll add that to my list of reasons why I don't use McAfee. Thanks

Comment: @KimJong-Un McAfee is very powerful and useful, other virus scanners don't do the job so good! that's why I use McAfee!

Comment: For what it's worth, AVG and Norton suck more- so don't worry about it. I use Microsoft Security Essentials (free) and wouldn't consider anything else right now on my personal computers (no noticeable performance impact, zero glitches such as the one you are posting about, and free.... although I'd happily pay for it if it wasn't).